# Interpreting Sql with where and having statement to linq giving different results

Tags: c#, sql, linq, where-clause, having

Please - I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT FK_ClassId, LectureDays
FROM tbl_TimeTables
WHERE Term = 'First Term' 
  AND FK_session = 4 
  AND fk_classId = 1 
  AND (fk_subjectid <> 1)
GROUP BY FK_classId, LectureDays
HAVING (COUNT(*) < 6)
```

This returns this result:

[Image Embedded Here, giving the right result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlOw7.png)

But when I interpret to linq, I get the a different result:

```
Tbl_TimeTables.GroupBy(x => new { x.FK_Session, x.Term, x.LectureDays,   
x.FK_ClassId, x.FK_SubjectId })
.Where(grp => grp.Count() < 6 && grp.Key.FK_Session == 4 && grp.Key.Term ==   
"First Term" && grp.Key.FK_ClassId == 1 && grp.Key.FK_SubjectId != 1)
.Select(grp => new 
{
  LectureDay = grp.Key.LectureDays,
  ClassId = grp.Key.FK_ClassId
})
```

[Wrong Results Picture Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqzaV.png)

Please look at my code, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Aren't you just grouping by different things in each query?

Comment: Actually, i never knew the power in words, Matt Gibson, you have actually pointed me in the right direction, i just couldn't see it before, but now i see it. I've posted the right linq query below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way the linq query should go according to Matt Gibson's suggestion:

```
Tbl_TimeTables
.Where(x => x.FK_Session == 4 && x.Term == "First Term" && x.FK_ClassId == 1   
&& x.FK_SubjectId != 1)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.FK_ClassId, x.LectureDays })
.Where(grp => grp.Count() < 6)
.Select(grp => new 
{
  ClassId = grp.Key.FK_ClassId,
  LectureDay = grp.Key.LectureDays
})
```

This works exactly like the sql
Also to point out that this link: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/definition-use-of-group-by-and-having-clause helped me in understanding how the having statement works, which helped in seeing what Matt what saying.